# ExtJS4.2 Grid Filter Leaves empty Rows with Paging - NewbieQ

Tags: grid, filtering, extjs4.2

I have tried various ways to refresh the grid but everything I try doesn't work.  Do I refresh the Grid or do I load the store??? You can see that the paging tool bar is still showing 50 pages after the filtering.  If there are no dates on a given pag and it is empty then it will disable the tool bar and paging doesn't work after that page un less you refresh the browser and skip over the empty page. So, in my case page 15 has no rows so it breaks when u hit next and get that page.  If you type in the page number 16 then all is good until you hit another's empty page. 
My datepicker is in my viewport below and I have tried refreshing the gird and loading the store as well as other things which mostly result in undefined error.  Not sure where to start with this one so I will show my code and screen shots below:

***BEFORE DATE SELECTION:***

[image]

***AFTER DATE SELECTION:***

[image]

***STORE:***

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync:true,
pageSize:50,
proxy:
{
    type: 'ajax',

     //extraParams :{limit:1000},

    api:
    {
        read: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2.cfc?method=getContent',
        update: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2-post.cfc?method=postContent'
    },
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success',
        totalProperty : 'dataset',
        remoteFilter : true
    },
    listeners:
    {
        // stuff goes here maybe??

    }
}   
});
```

***GRID PANEL:***

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.userlist',
title: 'All Users',
store: 'Users',
//buffered: true,
plugins:[Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {clicksToEdit: 2})],
dockedItems: [{ xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'Users',
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayMsg: 'Displaying Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                displayInfo: true}],


initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [
                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer',
                        {
                        resizable: true,
                        resizeHandles:'all',
                        align: 'center',
                        minWidth: 35,
                        maxWidth:50
                        }),
                    {
                    header: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'message_id',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'recip_email',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Date Time',
                    dataIndex: 'unix_time_stamp',
                    width: 120,
                    menuDisabled:true,
                    // submitFormat: 'd/m/Y',
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
                    field:{ xtype:'datefield',
                            autoSync:true,
                            allowBlank:false,
                            editor: new Ext.form.DateField(
                                    {format: 'm/d/y'})  }
                    }];


    this.callParent(arguments);

},

});
```

***VIEWPORT:***

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'AM',
appFolder: 'app',
controllers: ['Users'],

launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items:[{
            region: 'center',
            itemId:'centerPanelRegion',
            title:'The Title',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            hidden: true,
            activeTab: 0,
            items:[{
                    xtype: 'userlist',
                    listeners:
                    {
                        select: function(selModel, record, index, options)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('select');
                        },
                        add: function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('add - init2.js');
                        },
                        afterrender:function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('afterrender - userlist(init2.js)');
                        },
                        beforerender:function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('beforerender - userlist(init2.js)');
                        }
                    }
                  }]
            },
            {
            region: 'west',
            itemId:'westPanelRegion',
            hidden: true,
            layout:'fit',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activetab:0,
            collapsible:false,
            split: false,
            title: 'The Title',
            width:178,
            maxWidth:400,
            height: 100,
            minHeight: 100,
            items:[{
                    title: 'Tab 1',
                    xtype:'panel',
                    items:
                        [{
                        xtype: 'datepicker',
                        itemId:'datePickerFld',
                        listeners:{
                            beforerender: function(){
                                console.log('datepicker - beforerender(init2.js)');
                                var store = Ext.getStore('dates');
                                store.load({callback: function(){
                                console.log('datepicker - callback(init2.js');
                                console.log(store.data.items[999].data.recip_email);
                                console.log(store.data.items[999].data.unix_time_stamp);
                                }
                                })
                            }
                        },

                        handler: function(picker, date)
                            {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('date picker example in init2.js' + Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                            // get store by unique storeId
                            var store = Ext.getStore('Users');

                            // clear current filters
                             store.clearFilter(true);

                            // filter store
                            Ext.encode(store.filter("unix_time_stamp", Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y')));

                            //store.load();
                            //store.sync();

                            }
                        }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'ers may be added dynamically  - Others may be added dynamically',
            }]

         }]
    });
}
});
```

***CONTROLLER:***

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
stores:['Users', 'dates'],
models:['User', 'date'],
views: ['user.List','user.Edit'],


init: function() {

    Ext.getStore('dates').addListener('load',this.ondatesStoreLoad, this);

    this.control(
    {

        'viewport > userlist':
        {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser,
        },

        'useredit button[action=save]':
        {
            click: this.updateUser
        }           

    });

},


// ----------  handler Function declarations  -------------

ondatesStoreLoad: function(me,records,success)
{

// ------  Gets the dates from dates store and loads an array
var store = this.getStore('dates');
sendDataArray = [];

store.each(function(record){
    var recordArray = [record.get("unix_time_stamp")];
    sendDataArray.push(recordArray);
});         


// ------  Set DatePicker Bullshit right fucking here  --------//

var dtFld = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#datePickerFld')[0];

dtFld.setDisabledDates(["^(?!"+sendDataArray.join("|")+").*$"]);
dtFld.setMaxDate(new Date());
dtFld.setMinDate(new Date('05/01/2013'));


var wstPnlReg = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#westPanelRegion')[0];
wstPnlReg.show();

var ctrPnlReg = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#centerPanelRegion')[0];
ctrPnlReg.show();

// var grid = Ext.widget('userlist');

},

onUsersStoreDataChange: function(me)
{
    //console.log('Hey the store data just changed!');
},

editUser: function(grid, record)
{
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},

updateUser: function(button)
{
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
},

});
```

***UPDATED VIEWPORT:*** Changes made only in datepicker handler

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'AM',
appFolder: 'app',
controllers: ['Users'],

launch: function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items:[{
            region: 'center',
            itemId:'centerPanelRegion',
            title:'The Title',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            hidden: true,
            activeTab: 0,
            items:[{
                    xtype: 'userlist',
                    listeners:
                    {
                        select: function(selModel, record, index, options)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('select');
                        },
                        add: function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('add - init2.js');
                        },
                        afterrender:function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('afterrender - userlist(init2.js)');
                        },
                        beforerender:function(selModel)
                        {
                            // do something with the selected date
                            console.log('beforerender - userlist(init2.js)');
                        }
                    }
                  }]
            },
            {
            region: 'west',
            itemId:'westPanelRegion',
            hidden: true,
            layout:'fit',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activetab:0,
            collapsible:false,
            split: false,
            title: 'The Title',
            width:178,
            maxWidth:400,
            height: 100,
            minHeight: 100,
            items:[{
                    title: 'Tab 1',
                    xtype:'panel',
                    items:
                        [{
                        xtype: 'datepicker',
                        itemId:'datePickerFld',
                        listeners:{
                            beforerender: function(){
                                console.log('datepicker - beforerender(init2.js)');
                                var store = Ext.getStore('dates');
                                store.load({callback: function(){
                                console.log('datepicker - callback(init2.js');
                                console.log(store.data.items[999].data.recip_email);
                                console.log(store.data.items[999].data.unix_time_stamp);
                                }
                                })
                            }
                        },

                        handler: function(picker, date)
                            {
                                // do something with the selected date
                        console.log('date picker example in init2.js' + Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                        // get store by unique storeId
                            var store = Ext.getStore('Users');

                            // clear current filters
                             store.clearFilter(true);

                            // filter store
                            store.filter("unix_time_stamp", Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y'));

                        // Load the store
                        store.load();


                            }
                        }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'ers may be added dynamically  - Others may be added dynamically',
            }]

         }]
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is likely causing the issues.

```
Ext.encode(store.filter("unix_time_stamp", Ext.Date.format(date,'m/d/Y')));
```

I'm not sure why you are calling `Ext.encode` on whatever `store.filter` returns, but I don't think you want to do that (and it is likely causing the `undefined` errors).

As for the paging toolbar not updating the current count, it is likely you just aren't returning the correct information in your server response when updating the store. The server response should include the total number of records. According to the docs for `Ext.toolbar.Paging`, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging:

The packet sent back from the server would have this form:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "results": 2000,
    "rows": [ // ***Note:** this must be an Array
        { "id":  1, "name": "Bill", "occupation": "Gardener" },
        { "id":  2, "name":  "Ben", "occupation": "Horticulturalist" },
        ...
        { "id": 25, "name":  "Sue", "occupation": "Botanist" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I hate being stupid but i guess that is what comes with the territory when learning a new frame work.... my problem was that I was not getting a response back from the server as you suggested.  For whatever reason, the grid would filter the current rows in the grid but since I did not use the filter param in my CFC on the server side i got no love from the grid.  It seems my problem was being impatient and acting on the behavior of the what I saw in the grid.  I should have finished implementing the server side query to use my filter.  It would have returned the json packet and triggered load.

Comment: I am going to update my code in the post.  Hopefully someone can get use out of my frustrations and follow along and not make the same mistakes I am making.  Thanks again forgivinson for you efforts.  The reason for my issue was that i was not getting response back from my server call.