# ExtJS4.Grid Not Refreshing After Filtering with DatePicker - NewbieQ

Tags: gridview, extjs, datepicker

When I click on a date in my Date Picker I can see that the request is sent to my server, the query is made, the result set is returned but my grid does not appear to be refreshed....?!?! I have been struggling with learning this MVC pattern frame work and I can not believe the learning curve.  It seems the simplest things are not easy to do and when searching the net there are similiar posts but every single one is just a bit different than what I am trying to do or the poster has code in a different place or they not using MVC pattern..... blah blah blah....

The first trip to my server that populates my store with a query and therfore the grid is successful - No problems there.  At that point, if I pick a date from my date picker the call is made to the DB and the request is sent back with my JSON packet - No problem there.  I verified that the JSON packet in the first request matches the second and subsequent requests and everything is in check at that point when verified with chrome console and network tools.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

***User Store:***

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync:true,
pageSize:50,
proxy:
{
    type: 'ajax',

    api:
    {
        read: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2.cfc?method=getContent',
        update: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2-post.cfc?method=postContent'
    },
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success',
        totalProperty : 'dataset',
        remoteFilter : true
    },

    listeners:
    {
        // stuff goes here
    },
}
```

***Date Store:***

```
Ext.define('AM.store.dates', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.date',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync:true,
pageSize:1000,
proxy:
{
    type: 'ajax',
    api:
    {
        read: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2.cfc?method=getContent',
        update: 'http://192.168.0.103/testit/dao_2-post.cfc?method=postContent'
    },
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success',
        totalProperty : 'dataset',
        remoteFilter : true
    },

    listeners:
    {
        // stuff goes here
    }
```

***User Model:***

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        {name: 'message_id',type: 'textfield'},
        {name: 'recip_email',type: 'textfield'},
        {name: 'unix_time_stamp',type:'datefield', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}
        ]
});
```

***Date Model:***

```
    Ext.define('AM.model.date', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        {name: 'message_id',type: 'textfield'},
        {name: 'recip_email',type: 'textfield'},
        {name: 'unix_time_stamp',type:'datefield', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}
        ]
});
```

***Grid Panel:***

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.userlist',
title: 'All Users',
store: 'Users',
plugins:[Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {clicksToEdit: 1})],
dockedItems: [{ xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'Users',
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayMsg: 'Displaying Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                displayInfo: true}],


initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [
                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer',
                        {
                        resizable: true,
                        resizeHandles:'all',
                        align: 'center',
                        minWidth: 35,
                        maxWidth:50
                        }),
                    {
                    header: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'message_id',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'recip_email',
                    flex: 1,
                    editor:'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    menuDisabled:true
                    },
                    {
                    header: 'Date Time',
                    dataIndex: 'unix_time_stamp',
                    width: 120,
                    menuDisabled:true,
                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    field:{ xtype:'datefield',
                            editor: new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'Y-m-d'})  }
                    }];


    this.callParent(arguments);

}


});
```

***Controller:***

```
    Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
stores:['Users', 'dates'],
models:['User', 'date'],
views: ['user.List','user.Edit'],


init: function() {

    Ext.getStore('dates').addListener('load',this.ondatesStoreLoad, this);

    this.control(
    {

        'viewport > userlist':
        {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser,
        },

        'useredit button[action=save]':
        {
            click: this.updateUser
        }           

    });

},


// ----------  handler Function declarations  -------------

ondatesStoreLoad: function(me,records,success)
{

// ------  Gets the dates from dates store and loads an array
var store = this.getStore('dates');
sendDataArray = [];

store.each(function(record){
    var recordArray = [record.get("unix_time_stamp")];
    sendDataArray.push(recordArray);
});         


// ------  Set DatePicker here  --------//

var dtFld = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#datePickerFld')[0];

//dtFld.setDisabledDates(["^(?!"+sendDataArray.join("|")+").*$"]);
dtFld.setMaxDate(new Date());

var wstPnlReg = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#westPanelRegion')[0];
wstPnlReg.show();

var ctrPnlReg = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#centerPanelRegion')[0];
ctrPnlReg.show();

},


editUser: function(grid, record)
{
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},

updateUser: function(button)
{
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
},

});
```

***JSON Packet:***

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:05","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:06","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:07","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:07","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:08","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:09","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:09","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:09","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:09","recip_email":"test@aol.com"},{"message_id":"M42712027","unix_time_stamp":"2013-09-26 00:08:09","recip_email":"test@aol.com"}],"dataset":10}
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON response as well?  And possibly your code + JSON data on [Sencha's Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home)?

Comment: I added my JSON packet.  I have not used Fiddle yet so I will need to look at how to do that.

Comment: Ok, I finally got a working example... you can access it [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2mi).  After going through your example, I'm wondering if the issue is because your `grid panel` and `paging toolbar` are using two different stores... because you're passing the string value.  I would actually try creating a store and stashing it in a variable, and then supply that same variable to both the grid's store and the paging toolbar's store.  Also, if you look at the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-store), the store property does not take a string.

Comment: Also, I didn't see the code for your `date` model and `dates` store... am I just that blind?

Comment: No, your not blind.... I just added the date model and store. I am looking at your suggestion about the string.  I am not sure I understand though.  I see I am using the same 'Users' store but some how I should be using var? I am not sure I understand when to use var and when not to.  I thought it had to do with instancing now opposed to when the user needs it. That is over simplified of course.

Comment: BTW, thanks for your work getting fiddle set up with the grid.  I have been meaning to do that.

Comment: Well, what I'm unsure of is how Ext internally handles string valued stores... if you supply a string value of a store name to one spot in a grid, and then to a paging toolbar, does that ensure it's the same store?  What I'm getting at is, if you create a store and stash it in a variable, you know it's going to be the same store, but with using a string, I, as a programmer, don't know unless I look at Ext's code... which is something I do not want to do.  So my common practice is to look at the API and see that it doesn't let you use a string value.

Comment: But you are correct in saying you should be creating objects when you need them.  So in this case, I would probably override the `constructor` method of the grid, create a store in there, and then add it to the grid and paging toolbar.  I'll try to update my example to reflect this.

Comment: Part of my problem is that I started out using the example on sencha site and evolved it into what it is now.  In the begining i did not see anything in that example that used a var as the handle.  So, if you consider that and most examples on the net(and sencha) show code using var.  There is no ryhme or reason to how/when to use eitehr.  The only thing I notice is that it seems to have something to do with MVC pattern but even that is a broad stroke at describing what my issue is understanding how it should be done. if what my code does is not perfered method I am happy to throw it away and

Comment: start fresh with any suggestions.  I hope the way i am doing things is not my issue by which it is making it harder for me. I have considered buying a book but I know even then the examples will do something outside of what i have seen on the net making it a waste of money to spend on a book. if there is a way I should be structuring my program to fit the preferred method then please let me know. thanks again

Comment: Well, I got it working on my [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2mi).  The reason why I couldn't get it to work was because of that pesky `autoSync` property, as I'm not hooked up to an actual back-end.  I didn't even use the controller or date model/store... not quite sure what those last 2 are for, seeing as they're basically the same as the User definitions.

Comment: It is jus garbage derived from my pathetic learning curve.

Comment: I think what you're doing is the right way, at least, for a beginner.  I started out exactly like you... actually, that was in Ext JS 3.3 time, so there was way less documentation and no MVC.  But for starting out, you're doing just fine.  Reading the API is key, and just trying to actually understand what's going on is very important.  You seemed to have struggled to solve the problem before posting here, so you're definitely on the right path there.  Anyway, enough of my insight... let me know if that works for you!

Comment: incutonez... I didn't realize it until now but you just solved a different problem I was having.  Initially, the date field in the grid was working then it stopped working when I was trying to get my date picker to work.  I had yet to jump back into it to see why it stopped working but I see it working on your fiddle.  I have a screen shot i my other post that I should have linked to earlier.  None the less, you did solve an issue form me no doubt.

Comment: here is a link from my other post with screen shot........            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938144/extjs4-2-grid-filter-leaves-empty-rows-with-paging-newbieq

Answer (score 0):

I've just quickly put up a simple example of an ExtJS 4.2 MVC application that reloads a grid based on a filter field. http://hutten.org/bill/extjs/2014/01/simple-extjs-42-mvc-example.html